# PowerShell read from file search for string and remove unwanted text

Tags: powershell, dns

working on a script to backup DNS settings from a NIC and changing them back after some other actions.

`$BACKUP = Get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias WLAN* >>c:\tmp\dns.txt`

contents of dns.txt

```
InterfaceAlias               Interface Address ServerAddresses                                                                          
                             Index     Family                                                                                           
--------------               --------- ------- ---------------                                                                          
WLAN 2                               6 IPv4    {1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8}                                                                  
WLAN 2                               6 IPv6    {}
```

now for restoring i just need the 2 IP's between the {} so im starting with

```
$OLD = Get-Content C:\tmp\dns.txt | Select-String -Pattern 'ipv4' -SimpleMatch
```

what leaves me with

```
WLAN 2                               6 IPv4    {1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8}
```

but how do i get rid of the rest to get just the 2 IP's left in $Old

thx for help

Comment: This is probably better asked in [SO], but I don't think it's actually off-topic here.

Comment: thx Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style, indeed this is way better then getting lost in regex

Comment: Great, I've added my comments as an answer and deleted the comments since you confirm that is better. Feel free to check the little green mark next to the answer I submitted with this detail to the top left of it if you think it's worthy of acceptance for the answer you were seeking

Answer (score 0):

after trying some more i'll awnser my own question

```
$Old = Get-Content C:\tmp\dns.txt | Select-String -Pattern 'ipv4' -SimpleMatch
$Old = Get-TextWithin $Old -StartChar '{' -EndChar '}'
$DNS = $Old -split ',\s*'

function Get-TextWithin {
    
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory, 
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            Position = 0)]   
        $Text,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Single', Position = 1)] 
        [char]$WithinChar = '"',
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Double')] 
        [char]$StartChar,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Double')] 
        [char]$EndChar
    )
    $htPairs = @{
        '(' = ')'
        '[' = ']'
        '{' = '}'
        '<' = '>'
    }
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('WithinChar')) {
        $StartChar = $EndChar = $WithinChar
        if ($htPairs.ContainsKey([string]$WithinChar)) {
            $EndChar = $htPairs[[string]$WithinChar]
        }
    }
    $pattern = @"
(?<=\$StartChar).+?(?=\$EndChar)
"@
    [regex]::Matches($Text, $pattern).Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dump to text file, and parse strings with regex from it. The `Get-DnsClientServerAddress` command has an [`-AddressFamily`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/get-dnsclientserveraddress?view=windowsserver2022-ps#parameters) parameter where you specify `"IPv4"` to get just those addresses.

### PowerShell

```
(Get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias WLAN* -AddressFamily "IPv4").ServerAddresses
```

## Supporting Resources

- [Get-DnsClientServerAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/get-dnsclientserveraddress?view=windowsserver2022-ps)